# How can I use JavaScript/HTML/CSS to load a new page when a key is pressed down?

Tags: javascript, html, css, key, onkeypress

What would be the code for moving onto a new screen after a user presses a key. For example I have coded a blank screen that says press any key to begin.

I have been looking all over the web, but I am unable to find such a code that does not involve jQuery etc.

Thank you in advance.

```
<script>
    //created a variable for instructions
       var instructions = '<h1><center>You will see three different symbols appear</center></h1>';

    //Created a button
       var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.innerHTML = 'Click here to Start';

       var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.appendChild(button);
        button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if('click'){
            document.open(newPage)
        }
        });

    //Pressing a key (space bar in this case) will open up a blank page with the instructions of the experiment 
    document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==32){ 
        document.location.href=('about:blank');
        document.write(instructions)
}
});

</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is a pretty straightfoward thing to do. Hint: eventlisteners are your friend.

Comment: [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/503093/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's better to use EventListener

```
document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==65)//key code for 'a'
        location="http://google.com"
})
```

for a list of key codes: http://gcctech.org/csc/javascript/javascript_keycodes.htm

Comment: so instead of opening a URL webpage how would I be able to open a blank white screen?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. do you mean openning a blank page in a new window, navigating to a blank page, or erasing all the content in the current page?
note that if you navigate to a blank page you won't have control on that page because it's a different website.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do: A page opens with a message that says press any key to begin. Then a new page not a window opens with a set of instructions. After the instructions have been read a button can be clicked to move on to a new page to begin a trial version of an experiment. So far I have been able to make the 2nd page and the button. However the button appears on the first page and I cannot seem to open up a third page. Below I have pasted what I have written out so far

Comment: var instructions = '<h1><center>You will see three different symbols appear</center></h1>';
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerHTML = 'Click here to Start';
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]; body.appendChild(button); button.addEventListener('click', function(){ if('click'){document.open(newPage) } });        
 document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){ if(e.keyCode==32){ document.location.href=('about:blank'); document.write(instructions)
}});

Comment: instead of changing the location to "about:blank", you can use document.open(), which just erases all the html content. this way your javascript code will continue running.

Comment: by the way, if you write press any key to begin, you better not check if it's [space].. it is suppose to be any key.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
document.onkeydown= e => location='https://example.com'
```

```html
Click here and push some key
```

Comment: `addEventListener` is the preferred method for adding event listeners to DOM objects.